# Froala VUE v3 not showing toolbar buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, froala

I have updated the Froala Vue plugin to the last version `3.0.0-rc.2-1` and there is something weird going on. I only see just few buttons on the toolbar when I should see them all.

See screenshot:
[image]

In addition there isn't even the `quickInsertButtons` when creating a new line.
I have a configuration with many things setup from the previous version, I tried to delete it and leave just the plain editor with everything on default but the result is the screenshot I have attached. So it is not my config (which worked perfectly fine on the previous version), but the new Vue version of it. I'm saying the Vue version because the regular Froala version (without VUE) is working properly.

HERE A SANDBOX THAT SHOWS THE PROBLEM: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-froala-s6lie

On the demo, in App.vue see the buttons enabled on the toolbar and the ones that are actually shown on the editor.

Comment: I'm having the _exact_ same problem, so it does appear as though the Vue version is borked.

Comment: I open the same issue on their github. Check here: https://github.com/froala/vue-froala-wysiwyg/issues/95